# Get file name and assign it as a column name in a function

Tags: r

I've got several `csv` files that all have this format:

```
xyz         site
2.1         tex1
15.67       tex2
32.111      ny31
```

I want to import these files into R. Like this:

```
df_list <- list.files('./usa_data') 
dfs <- lapply(df_list, import_function)
```

What I want the `import_function` to do is to take a part of the name of the csv file and paste it instead of the first column name (`xyz`). My csv names have this format:

```
usa_low_dollars_270_1.csv
usa_high_euros_250_2.csv
usa_low_gbp_240_1.csv
```

I want to extract the currency (the third component of the name), combine it with the word 'median' and rename the first column like this:

```
dollars_median  site
2.1             tex1
15.67           tex2
32.111          ny31

# or 

euros_median  site
2.1             tex1
15.67           tex2
32.111          ny31

# etc
```

Comment: Which of the two is exactly the problem? (1) getting the file names. (2) extracting the currency substring.

Comment: Hi Jan! The second one. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply` along the indices of `df_list` using `seq_along` instead of on the vector itself.

From there you can subset `df_list` with the index and assign the column names of the read in data using `strsplit`.

```
df_list <- list.files()
df_list
[1] "usa_high_euros_250_2.csv"  "usa_low_dollars_270_1.csv" "usa_low_gbp_240_1.csv"   

lapply(seq_along(df_list), function(x){
  data <- read.csv(df_list[x])
  names(data)[1] <- str_c(strsplit(df_list[x],"_")[[1]][3],"_median")
  data
})
[[1]]
  euros_median site
1        2.100 tex1
2       15.670 tex2
3       32.111 ny31

[[2]]
  dollars_median site
1          2.100 tex1
2         15.670 tex2
3         32.111 ny31

[[3]]
  gbp_median site
1      2.100 tex1
2     15.670 tex2
3     32.111 ny31
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the `dollar` or the other currencies on the 3. place of the string, so:

```
sp <- stringr::str_split("usa_low_dollars_270_1.csv", '_')[[1]][3]
sp
[1] "dollars"
```

you can then make your new name like so:

```
new <- paste0(sp, '_median')
new
[1] "dollars_median"
```

With this you can exchange the colname.

Comment: it is also possible to get around the dependency to the stringr package with the base R function `strsplit()`.

Comment: Thank you. How can I do this so I don't have to type in the name of each file (I have 30+ files), but rather that the function recognises the name of the csv? In the first line of your code, `str_split`